# How do I enable captions for the YouTube videos when using the SXA video component?

Tags: sxa

Sitecore 8.2.7 : SXA 1.7.0

We would like to enable the captions auto generated by YouTube in the videos on our site. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about having those captions:

[image]

Then it is will be gone when you turn on poster quality.

You have two options:

- change the script and remove poster quality if you are using it
- use HTML Snippet component and insert embedded code for YouTube player.

You can change the player options in component-video.js:

```javascript
// possible youtube imageQuality values: `default`, `hqdefault`, `mqdefault`, `sddefault` and `maxresdefault`
$.extend(properties, {
    plugins: ["youtube", "flash", "silverlight"],
    silverlightName: "silverlightmediaelement.xap",
    classPrefix: "mejs-",
    success: callback,
    stretching: "auto",
    pluginPath: "../other/",
    youtube: {
        imageQuality: 'maxresdefault' 
    }
});
```